# What is the 'right' topology for this space?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ be an open set and consider the space $H^{\infty}(\Omega)$, the space of holomorphic and bounded functions on $\Omega$. We can endow this space with the supremum norm making it a metric space and then $f_n\rightarrow f$ in this topology iff $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly on $\Omega$.

Now if i want to construct a topology on $H^{\infty}_{0,1}(\Omega)$ the space of holomorphic and bounded functions on $\Omega$ with bounded derivative. I want to have $f_n\rightarrow f$ in this topology iff **both** $f_n\rightarrow f$ **and** $f_n'\rightarrow f'$ uniformly on $\Omega$, which is the right topology i should consider? I thought that maybe it is the one endowed by the norm $\left \| \cdot  \right \|_{der}=\left \| \cdot  \right \|+\left \| \cdot  \right \|'$, where $\left \| f \right \|=\underset{z\in\Omega}{sup}|f(z)|$ and $\left \| f \right \|'=\underset{z\in\Omega}{sup}|f'(z)|$. Am i correct or is there some other well-known topology making this work?

Also, what happens if i want to generalize this to an infinite (denumerable) number of derivatives, modifying the definition of the space accordingly? The sum may not work, i guess i should think of the topology defined by seminorms, right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A Theorem of Weierstrass says: If (f_n) is a sequence of holomorphic functions which converges uniformly on $\Omega $ to f, then f is holomorphic and $(f_n^{'})$ converges uniformly to $f^{'}$